# Column will not receive correct value when using wordpress insert or update commands

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I wrote a simple script that I am using in a chat program to track active sessions:

```
<?PHP
require_once("../../../../wp-load.php");
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
global $wpdb;

session_start();


function getSessionInfo() {
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "chat_sessions";
    $activeSession = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $table_name ." WHERE sessionid = '". session_id()."'");
    return $activeSession[0];
}

function updateSession ($active = false)
{
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . "chat_sessions";
    $activeSession = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ". $table_name ." WHERE sessionid = '". session_id()."'");

    $timestamp = gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());

    if ($activeSession) {
        if ($active) {
            $wpdb->update( $table_name, array('passive' => $timestamp, 'active' => $timestamp), array('sessionid' => session_id()));
        } else {
            $wpdb->update( $table_name, array('passive' => $timestamp), array('sessionid' => session_id()));
        }
    } else {
        $wpdb->insert( $table_name, array('sessionid' => session_id(), 'passive' => $timestamp, 'active' => $timestamp));
    }
}
```

I have 2 columns that are my last active datetimes. One is active and one is passive. The passive one is updated every few seconds through ajax just from the user being on the page. The active one is updated when the user physically does something; it's split like this so I can set different timeouts for each.

Problem is my active column NEVER gets the timestamp, not when its first created or when I specifically call `updateSession(true);` despite the table fields being identically set up and it populating from the same time variable. The field will always read '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

Comment: because you never set any value to `$active` variable. so when you check `if ($active) {` it is ALWAYS NULL there...

Comment: ooops... just found `updateSession ($active = false)`  so you have your `false` default value. show us the place where you do call `update Session()` function?

Comment: for the purpose of testing Ive just been adding a line `updateSession(true);` to this file and running it directly

Comment: what do you mean by Directly??

Comment: buy typing the files URL into the location bar, opposed to it being included in with the rest of my application.

Comment: and how can you pass the parameter to the function using url??

Comment: what? The function gets its argument when I add the `updateSession(true);`. The TRUE is the argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified my date time string to include quotes incase wordpress's sql string formatter was omitting them and the space between date and time was throwing things off.

```
$timestamp = "'".gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())."'";
```

That worked for me. Still not sure why it worked for the first column, assume its something to do how wordpresses sql query is combined.